# 'Extra argument in call' swift and sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift

I have an error with my swift code, I use the sprite kit engine.
This is my code:

```
func addEnemy() {
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "EnemySprite")

    let randX = random(0, self.size.height) // extra argument in call

    var spawnPos =CGPointMake(CGFloat(randX), CGFloat(self.size.height + enemy.size.height / 2))          
    enemy.position = spawnPos
    self.addChild(enemy)
}
```

Comment: Do random() accepts any argument ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random()` doesn't take any arguments.

Your best best is to use `arc4random_uniform()` like so:

```
let randX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height + 1))
```

`arc4random_uniform()` returns an `UInt32` between `0` and 1 less than the value passed as an argument. So to get a number between `0` and the height, add one to the height and pass it in.

Comment: you will need to cast the height to UInt32 as arc4random_uniform expects UInt32 argument type

Comment: I changed 'Int32' to 'UInt32' now it's working, Thanks!

Comment: @marnix Please don't forget to upvote and select a correct answer.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `random()` function available in the swift `stdlib`, It's declared like:

```
func random() -> Int
```

It won't take any argument.

**NOTE:** If you defined your own random() function, please post it along with the question.